# Windows 8 - Search in explorer doesn't work anymore

Tags: windows-8, search

It's been a few days now, windows search simply doesn't work anymore. Whatever I type into the search field, it displays "searching", the blue bar moves, but no files are shown, ever. I can even search in an empty folder it simply keeps on searching and never tells me that it's empty. Start8 search does exactly the same. What can I do ?

Comment: What have you tried to fix it? What resources did you look up online that didn't work?

Comment: I tried rebooting, rebuilding the index.
Also, search on an external device (hard drive or usb key) WORKS, but on my internal SSD it doesnt

Comment: Have you checked that your drive is in good condition with a CHKDSK?

Comment: Today I opened a folder full of files.  I wanted to find files with the word 'restore' in the file name.  I typed 'restore' in the search box and nothing came up.  I then looked through the files and found one called 'Restore Database.sql'.  I've googled around but my solution ended up being to turn off the Windows Search service (indexing).  Searching now is slower, but at least it can handle simple searches like the one I described here!